# Async - DataReader HasRows but reader.Read() doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, sqldatareader

I've looked at dozens of threads now trying to find the solution, but I seem to have everything in place per the Microsoft documentation here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a674khd(v=vs.110).aspx) and according to the SO threads I've seen.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

When I run the code below, I get no data from the DataReader on reader.Read().  HasRows shows True, but no data is read.  When "while(reader.Read())" is hit, it skips the following section, indicating (I believe) that there's no data in the reader.  When I run a test query that's just basically "SELECT Top 1 * from tableName", I do get results, so I believe my code is formatted correctly for getting data out of the reader.

Note, I'm not showing all the data for brevity...the SQL query is correct, as I've copied from the inspection window during execution directly into SSMS with parameters, and values are returned correctly.  The switch statement in the last section is truncated to save space.  The class DataHolder is simply a list of a couple other classes (like "Type1") to stage the data for upload later.

```
static async Task<DataHolder> DataBuilder(string type)
    {
        var constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BS-CW"].ConnectionString;
        var start = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month, 1); 
        var end = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMilliseconds(-1); //getting all the data for the previous month
        var holder = new DataHolder();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query(type), con))
        {
            // Query(type) does produce the correct SQL query, as tested in SSMS
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 1800; //30 min timeout
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", start);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", end);

            con.Open();

            IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteReader();

            var count = 0;
            var totalCount = 0;
            while (!result.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (count < 60)
                {
                    count++;
                    Console.Write(".");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 0;
                    totalCount++;
                    Console.WriteLine($"{totalCount} minute(s) waited...");
                }
            }

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.EndExecuteReader(result))
            {
                holder = AddData(type, reader);
            }
        }
        return holder;
    }

static DataHolder AddData(string type, SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        var holder = new DataHolder();

        switch (type)
        {
            case "type1":
                while (reader.Read()) // FAILS HERE == NO DATA IN READER??
                {
                    var data = new Type1()
                    {
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]),
                        DeviceId = Convert.ToInt64(reader["DeviceId"]),
                        Value = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Type1"])
                    };
                    holder.Type1List.Add(data);
                }
                break;
           default:
             break;
        }
    return holder;
}
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    cast(scantime as date) as [Date]
    ,d.deviceid as [DeviceId]
    ,CASE WHEN AVG([cpu_usage]) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE AVG([cpu_usage]) END as [CPU]
FROM 
    [ods_10_ds1].[dbo].[datacpu_detailed] [data]
    join task t on [data].taskid = t.taskid
    join device d on t.deviceid = d.deviceid
    join customer c on d.customerid = c.customerid
where
    cast(scantime as date) >= @startdate
    and cast(scantime as date) <= @enddate
    and deviceclassid = 106
    and enabled = 1
    and d.deviceid in (1433949,9667189)
group by 
    cast(scantime as date), d.deviceid
order by
    cast(scantime as date), d.deviceid
```

Comment: The OP uses the old approach to asynchonicity, the one that uses the [BeginExecuteReader approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/1a674khd(v=vs.110).aspx). Pointing them instead to a newer, task-based APIs, doesn't solve their issue.

Comment: To the OP: double check your connection string, you could be mistakenly testing two different databases, one in SSMS, the other in your code.

Comment: Could it be that your date values are being incorrectly interpreted/casted by the less explicit `.AddWithValue` method ? Perhaps, as a test, use the `SqlParameter param1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate",System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime)` and then `param.Value = start`.  This is just a guess though since your code all looks correct and your cmd doesn't sound like it's throwing an error, suggesting you are getting back 0 results.

Comment: @DavidL You're correct, I don't have proper async use in this because I'm just trying to get the data out.  I'll add async in once I'm confident in the data.  Or do you recommend a completely different approach, as Wiktor mentions?

Comment: @JNevill Not a bad point...I'll investigate further on that

Comment: @WiktorZychla The connection string was copy/pasted from another project that uses this database and has no issues.  Uses a synchronous setup, though.  An async call like this shouldn't change anything with that, should it?

Comment: In case it helps... "[Can we stop using AddWithValue?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)" .

Comment: @Richardissimo Fair point.  I tried with the "cmd.Parameters.Add(x).Value = val" command, thought, but had the same results.